# PHP, SQL-Request, no Output

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Im struggling around with a request on my SQL-Database and dont know where the mistake is. This is the head of the function I have:

```
    public function loadDownloadData(){
        $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
        $sqlreq = "SELECT Name, Pfad, Groesse, Beschreibung FROM download INNER JOIN user_download ON download.Name = user_download.Download_Name WHERE  User_Name = '$userID'";
        $downloadFile = DatabaseConnector::getData($sqlreq);
        if($downloadFile != null){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($downloadFile)){
```

my Problem is that $downloadFile is empty. Although the function jumps in the if-Clause. If i try the request in phpMyAdmin i get the correct result. The $userID - Variable has also the correct String in it. 
I really appreciate any tips and suggestions.

Thanks guys

Comment: What is `DatebaseConnector`? That's not one of the usual MySQL APIs from PHP.

Comment: If DatabaseConnector works as advertised. `User_Name = '$userID' ` looks strange should it be something like `User_Id = '$userID'` or `User_Name = '$userName'` ?

Comment: `User_Name` field belongs to which table `download` or `user_download`? `DatabaseConnector::getData` what is that framework or library you use?

Comment: DatabaseConnector is a class which handles the connection to my database. It is static so i can call it with DatabaseConnector::getData(). This method works perfectly when i call it from other methods i use. User_Name is the name of the row of my user_download table and $userID holds the right information. i tried the method with this sql-request: `$sqlreq = "SELECT Name,Pfad,Groesse,Beschreibung FROM download WHERE Name = 'testfile'";`. But it did not work,too.